# No version of NDK matched the requested version in nativescript 7.0.11

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

After updating `nativescript` to latest version `7.0.11` I created a new project and just run it using `tns run android` and I get this error

```
No version of NDK matched the requested version 20.0.5594570. Versions available locally: 21.3.6528147
```

Then based on [update gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) I tried to change gradle version in `~\platforms\android\build.gradle` like

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4' // tried for 4.0.0 , 4.1.0 also
...
...
    }
```

for both `4.0.0`,`4.1.0` I'm getting different errors And that's not worth showing here.

how to solve this issue ?

Comment: get rid of all your platforms folder with `ns clean` then run `ns doctor` to see if you have correct versions of andoid sdk and java

Comment: @cemkaan I solved it by changing `gradle:3.6.4` to `gradle:3.5.4`. But, why `3.6.4` was not working is a mystery. This question must be answered by nativescript community people.